# SwitchCompat not animating correctly in NavigationView's Menu when hiding a SubMenu

Tags: android, android-appcompat, navigationview, switchcompat

I have a `NavigationView` with the usual `Menu` inside it. I add two items: one regular item with an action view containing a `SwitchCompat` in the xml definition and a submenu with several items from code. This works just fine.

[image]

I use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on the switch to check when its state changes and if it is set on I hide the submenu (`catMenu`):

```
final Menu naviMenu = navi.getMenu(); // Already contains the switch element in XML definition
final SubMenu catMenu = naviMenu.addSubMenu("Kategoriat");

final SwitchCompat onlyfavsw = (SwitchCompat)naviMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_onlyfavs).getActionView();
onlyfavsw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b)
    {
        catMenu.getItem().setVisible(!b);
    }
});
```

The hiding/showing works fine, except the `SwitchCompat` doesn't animate correctly. It changes color, but the switch doesn't move to the right side. I can manually slide it there, but not back.

[image]

The same thing happens if I remove the submenu from the menu inside the event. So I think any tampering with the menu causes issues with the animation.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in the compatibility libraries? Any other way to handle hiding a submenu based on a selection?

I'm using version 23.1.1 of appcompat-v7

Answer (score 0):

This indeed seems to be a bug. I have the same problem. If I click on the Switch itself it animates fine but if I change the switch state while the NavigationDrawer is open there is no animation.

See this for the Android Issue Tracker entry: [SwitchCompat.setChecked does not animate inside RecyclerView](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196652)